# How to use jQuery .remove() on div created using while/fetch in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a Bootstrap modal that displays both Read and Unread messages from a database:

[image: Message Modal]

It shows a notification badge (see top) if there are unread messages. I've added a delete button, but can't figure out how to remove the entire div that contains that specific button, including the hr tag. The problem is that it only deletes the second div and hr tag you see there, but not the first. I even have an alert set up and it shows me the correct div id for the second. The first does nothing. This is what I tried. It's the code for the entire modal div:

```
<div id="messages_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-messages-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal_label">Messages
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <?php
            $subject = "";
            $query = "SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE username=?";
            if (!$stmt = $connection->prepare($query)) {
                echo $stmt->error;
            } else {
                if (!$stmt->bind_param('s', $username)) {
                    echo $stmt->error;
                } else {
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($recip_id);
                    $stmt->fetch();
                    $stmt->close();
                }
            }
            $query = "SELECT username, avatar, conversation_id, conversation_subject, time, msg_seen FROM `users` INNER JOIN `conversation` ON `users`.id = `conversation`.user_1
                          WHERE user_2 = ? ORDER BY time DESC";
            if (!$stmt = $connection->prepare($query)) {
                echo $stmt->error;
            } else {
                if (!$stmt->bind_param('i', $recip_id)) {
                    echo $stmt->error;
                } else {
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($sender_name, $avatar, $msg_id, $subject, $timestamp, $msg_seen);
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                        $div_count++;
                        if ($msg_seen == 0) {
                            $notification_count++;
                        }
                        $subject = (strlen($subject) > 16) ? substr($subject, 0, 14) . '...' : $subject;
                        ?>
```

STARTING POINT OF WHERE I WANT TO DELETE

```
                        <div id="msg_content_<?php echo $div_count;?>" class="msg-content">
                            <div class="avatar-container">
                                <a href="../pages/messages.php?id=<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="lighten"><img
                                            src="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" class="msg-avatar"></a>
                                <div class="text-container">
                                    <span class="show-sender"><?php echo $sender_name; ?></span>
                                    <span class="show-msg-status"><?php
                                        if ($msg_seen == 0) {
                                            echo "Unread";
                                        } else {
                                            echo "Read";
                                        }
                                        ?></span>
                                    <br/>
                                    <span class="show-msg"> Subject: <em><?php echo $subject; ?></em></span>
                                    <button id="msg_delete_btn_<?php echo $div_count;?>" class="delete-btn">delete</button>
                                    <br/>
                                    <span class="show-timestamp"><?php echo date('D, F jS, Y h:i A', strtotime($timestamp)); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr id="<?php echo $div_count;?>">
```

ENDING POINT OF WHERE I WANT TO DELETE

```
                     <?php
                    }
                    $stmt->close();
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot of what I need deleted:

[image: Div needing deleted]

Here is my jQuery. The alert shows me "msg_delete_btn_2", which is the correct dynamically generated id, but it this is only working for 2nd message.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#msg_delete_btn_<?php echo $div_count;?>').click(function() {

        $('#msg_content_<?php echo $div_count;?>').remove(); //<-- REMOVES DIV
        $('#<?php echo $div_count;?>').remove(); //<-- REMOVES <hr> TAG
        alert(this.id); //<-- SHOWS ME "msg_delete_btn_2" for 2nd div, which is correct. First div does nothing.

    });
});
```

So, how can I access any div via the delete button? I tried giving the button and the div their own id by creating a count variable to no avail.

Comment: You're using PHP to create HTML. You're using jQuery to work on the structure created by that HTML. There is no relationship between PHP and jQuery here.

Comment: I'm going to work on an ajax function to remove from database later. It removes the 2nd div when I click the delete button, but not the first. How do I grab the correct element then if it's only working for the 2nd one?

Comment: what's the error shown in your console?

Comment: Strangely, no errors. I didn't think to mention that since there weren't any shown. I used the button class name instead of the id and it deletes the div, except for the hr tag. Closer than I was before though.

Comment: Open generated js code and see what is in `$('#msg_delete_btn_<?php echo $div_count;?>')` string.

Comment: After using the button class instead of the id, it keeps saying $div_count is 2, even when I click div 1. ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that after all iterations of a `while`, variable `$div_count` holds the last value.

So, if you have two rows, your js code becomes:

```
$('#msg_delete_btn_2').click(/* other code */);
```

So your code knows nothing about other `msg_delete_btn_` buttons.

The simple solution is to use `class` instead, you already have it `delete-btn`, or add another class:

```
$('.delete-btn').click(function() {
    // remove following hr element which is after closest `div.msg-content` in which this button is
    $( this ).closest( ".msg-content" ).next( "hr" ).remove();        
    // remove closest `div.msg-content` in which this button is
    $( this ).closest( ".msg-content" ).remove();   // remove 

    // first `hr` then `div` because if you first
    // delete `div` then `hr` WILL NOT BE FOUND
});
```

More sopisticated solution (if your markup will change) can be to store current `$div_count` in a `data` attribute of a button and generate proper `ids` using it. Something like:

```
<button data-id="<?php echo $div_count;?>" class="delete-btn">delete</button>

$('.delete-btn').click(function() {
    var itemId = $( this ).data( "id" );
    $( "msg_content_" + itemId ).remove();
    // more codes
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the 2nd solution. The first still doesn't remove the hr tag. I'm going to try the data attribute (never seen that until now) and let you know. :-)

Comment: I fixed my code. `hr` stays on page because you deleted `div` first. As `div` is deleted - then `hr` cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, It should work!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.delete-btn').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.msg-content').next('hr').remove(); //<-- REMOVES <hr> TAG
        $(this).closest('.msg-content').remove(); //<-- REMOVES DIV
    });
})();
```

Comment: Dang. So close, but the hr tags remain. I tried .closest previously, but had the wrong syntax. Thanks for showing me the correct way to use it. I just need to figure out the hr issue.

Comment: Swap lines. If you first delete `div` then `hr` will not be found as `div` already deleted.

Comment: @u_mulder is right, there is a working demo on [codepen](http://codepen.io/niklakhani/pen/yMpEZb)

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` and remove the unnecessary `id` tags.

You can use `$(this)` to target the current element and the closest `.msg-content` class.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-btn', function(){
  $(this).closest('.msg-content').remove();
});
```

Another improvement:

No need to have `hr` tags instead give the them a style of `border-bottom:1px solid #d3d3d3;`

```
.msg-content{border:1px solid #d3d3d3;}
.msg-content:last-child{border:1px solid transparent;} /* Hide border of last element */
```